# why is my female rat suddenly biting and pulling my other rats tails?

Tags: behavior, rat

we have had rats for 12 years and we have never had something like this happen before.
we have had our 3 rats for 2+ years now they are all female and have always got a long perfectly fine.
just today rosie started biting at the other girls tails and pulling hard. she also was biting one of their necks too.
we separated them for abit and then put her back with the other 2 but she instantly went to bite and pull on them again.
anyone have any idea wht shes doing this as we have never experienced this before.
thanks!

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! When did the ratd last time see a vet? If the behaviour of pets in general changes suddenly, then the owners need to exclude any pain or health issues by seeing a vet.

Comment: I would think the same - to see the vet - maybe she's in pain so that suddenly she got so anxious. Or maybe something changed in the environment that make her nervous?